# Converting to plain text in python

Tags: python, string, text, utf-8

I have a dataframe column (`"albums"`) where most values are coded in plain text (ex: `"Album"`, `"Album 2"`, etc.) but some values have `utf-8` or other values combined with plain text. For example, instead of the text `"Précis"` I have `"Pr\xc3\xa9cis."` There also appears to be some `HTML` coding, for example `"\&#x27;"` in place of apostrophes within text.

Is there a simple way to convert everything to plain text without searching and replacing for each possible utf/unicode/html?

Comment: For HTML codes you may try some functions in `urllib.parse` . For `\xc3\xa` you can try together `encode()` with `decode()` but with different values - see [Standard Encodings¶](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings). Probably you will need encoding `raw_unicode_escape` or `unicode_escape` or both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `\xc3\xa9` you need combination `encode()` and `decode()` with `raw_unicode_escape`

```
print( "Pr\xc3\xa9cis.".encode('raw_unicode_escape').decode() )
```

---

Doc: codecs [Python Specific Encodings](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#python-specific-encodings)

---

And for `&#x27;` you need `html.unescape`

```
import html

print(html.unescape("&#x27;"))
```

---

Doc: [html](https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.html#html.unescape)